# Firebase Delete push subscriptions

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM Firebase and Api for Server Reference.

I've used the Delete request to https://iid.googleapis.com/v1/web/iid/REGISTRATION_TOKEN to remove a device from all threads.

But now this device can not subscribe for any other topic.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you expound more on the details? How can you tell that *the device can not subscribe for any other topic*?

Comment: I have the same experience (using a variant of the [firebase quickstart code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging). I created a subscription to a topic using the reg token. Then I called the delete method. Then I tried to (re)create a subscription to the same topic. The URL 404s ( & info 404s e.g)

GET https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/ejjVs8EX...EAWjG?details=true 404 ()

This particular API Doc is confusing. It says it's the way to delete a topic subscription, but the topic never appears in the call? Seems to just delete the registration token entirely!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same with me. My token was deleted too. But I solved it!!! Yeah!
I`d just removed the application and re-downloaded it!
Few seconds later, I could see that Firebase returns a new instance token!!
(after several tcp connections... in the Xcode debug window for simulation)
I think FCM can automatically assign the token!